# Choosing a good RF library for transmissions

Tags: esp32, rf, attiny85

I am trying to send information from an **Attiny85 to an ESP32, through RF**.
I am using the most popular 433mhz transmitter on the market.

I know various existing libraries to send and receive data between chip on rf hardware ;

Here are the following ones I tried :

- Manchester
- RC Switch
- Radio Head

All of those seems to be working well enough, but aren't very constant in the range. **I'm having a lot of troubles receiving correct data a few meters away indoors.**

As I am not an expert in radio waves, I would like to have an explanation on what radio protocol can be trusted for simple applications, and what not to use.
I know that a simple encoding like HIGH level for digital 1, and low level for digital 0 can be compromised, and that the manchester encoding is a better idea, but I would like to have a better understanding on how it works.

Comment: what leads you to believe that the library is the cause of the problem?

Comment: I don't believe any library might be the problem, but that differents protocol will offer different speed. For example I would like to send the received data to another chip, and the receiving speed matters. But I don't really know what protocols they use, and what is the difference between them. In my application the code seems to slow down reception, as I'm not sure how it works, I think the way reception is handled might change things, but I'm not sure... I also didn't really know how to put the question...